# Why can't I upgrade firmware on my Thinkpad after upgrade from 20.04 to 20.10?

Tags: upgrade, firmware, fwupd

I upgraded my Thinkpad laptop from Ubuntu 20.04 to 20.10. All went well. However, there's now firmware updates available but when I try to apply them I get an error saying:

> Unable to update "System Firmware": missing signed bootloader
> for secure boot: /usr/libexec/fwupd/efi/-fwupdx64.efi.signed can not
> be found

How do I fix this so I can update firmware? Shouldn't this be taken care of during the system upgrade?

Answer (score 12):

Run the command `apt install fwupd-signed` and try install again.

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution to this problem: For some reason a package called 'fwupd-signed' was not installed in 20.10 but must have been on 20.04 since I was able to upgrade firmware without problems. So the upgrade process from 20.04 to 20.10 left me without this package needed for firmware updates.

Comment: How did you fix this? I have the same issue on a Dell XPS 13 7390 BTX running Ubuntu 20.04. I've tried `sbctl sign -s /usr/libexec/fwupd/efi/fwupdx64.efi -o /usr/libexec/fwupd/efi/fwupdx64.efi.signed` but it doesn't seem to work, and that's all I can think of...