# Package fwupd-signed being kept back on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.10

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  fwupd-signed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

---

```
apt-cache policy fwupd fwupd-signed
fwupd:
  Installed: 1.5.8-0ubuntu1pop0~1617221312~20.10~a9de48d
  Candidate: 1.5.8-0ubuntu1pop0~1617221312~20.10~a9de48d
  Version table:
 *** 1.5.8-0ubuntu1pop0~1617221312~20.10~a9de48d 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.4.7-0~20.10.2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates/main amd64 Packages
     1.4.5-1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/main amd64 Packages
fwupd-signed:
  Installed: 1.5.8-0ubuntu1pop0~1617221312~20.10~a9de48d
  Candidate: 1.30.2+1.4.7-0~20.10.2
  Version table:
     1.30.2+1.4.7-0~20.10.2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates/main amd64 Packages
     1.30+1.4.5-1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.5.8-0ubuntu1pop0~1617221312~20.10~a9de48d 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Relating https://askubuntu.com/q/1287737/619216

Comment: I would `sudo apt update` & ensure there are no warnings/errors that you missed, then perform a full-upgrade, ie. `sudo apt full-upgrade` (as upgrade doesn't perform upgrades in certain circumstances, see `man apt` for clues.. full-upgrade is there for when you want to do that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a package is "kept back", that means the `upgrade` command will not upgrade it because doing so would require installing or removing other packages.  You can override this with the `install` command:

```
sudo apt-get install fwupd-signed
```

It will list which packages it has to install or remove in order to upgrade that, so make sure it's not removing anything you care about.

In your case, it looks like you have versions of fwupd and fwpupd-signed that were provided by Pop_OS!, but you no longer have the Pop_OS! repositories configured.  If you are using Pop, you should add their repositories, then try doing `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` again: https://apt.pop-os.org/

If you're not using Pop, then you can force Ubuntu to install its versions instead.  Try:

```
sudo apt install fwupd=1.4.7-0~20.10.2 fwupd-signed=1.30.2+1.4.7-0~20.10.2
```

Comment: It won't let me reply to your other answer, but I've updated my answer with a step that I think will fix it.

Comment: sudo apt install fwupd=1.4.7-0~20.10.2 fwupd-signed=1.30.2+1.4.7-0~20.10.2
this command fix the problem thx