# Unable to update “Dell Inc. System Firmware”: missing signed bootloader for secure boot: /usr/libexec/Fwupd/efi/- Fwupdx64.efi.signed cannot be found

Tags: updates, dell, bootloader, firmware

[image]

I have a Dell XPS 13 7390 BTX, running Ubuntu 20.04. I've noticed this error when updating my programs, specifically "Dell System Firmware 1.5.1 > 1.9.0".

The closest to a solution I found is from https://github.com/Foxboron/sbctl/issues/10#issuecomment-648442565, recommending:

`sbctl sign -s /usr/libexec/fwupd/efi/fwupdx64.efi -o /usr/libexec/fwupd/efi/fwupdx64.efi.signed`

I did so and the output was:

```
Command 'sbctl' not found, did you mean:

  command 'sbcl' from deb sbcl (2:2.0.1-3)
  command 'bbctl' from deb bit-babbler (0.8build1)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

Trying to instal `sbctl` I went to https://github.com/Foxboron/sbctl but it wasn't clear how to install it, there nor on the README file.

Other things I tried were [Why can't I upgrade firmware on my Thinkpad after upgrade from 20.04 to 20.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287737/why-cant-i-upgrade-firmware-on-my-thinkpad-after-upgrade-from-20-04-to-20-10) (similar but the person had this package on 20.04 and just lost it in the process of upgrading to 20.10, so it seems like they reverted to 20.04 and got it back from there) and https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd/issues/2219 (seems to have fixed it by pushing an update further upstream but it's not clear what to do when the error still occurs).

Is there a way of fixing this?

### Update

The problem persists but when I click "update" a message box appears saying an update has been installed and a restart is required:

[image]

... and then a few seconds later an error message shows up showing a failure in downloading repository information (the internet connection is fine):

[image]

Comment: Sounds like this is a question for Dell. Not sure how a Think pad issue applies to a Dell machine.

Comment: Me neither, but such hacks are what the internet was built on ;)